# Ansible: If a file exists on remote host, echo out the contents of the file

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I have an ansible playbook, and one of it tasks depends on if a file exists, if it does, I want to trigger next task and echo out the contents of the file.

here's block of the code:

```
---
- name: If Pass File Exists
  stat:
    path: /var/lib/File
  register: result

- name: Read Password
  when: result.changed
  shell: cat /var/lib/File
  changed_when: false
  register: adm_pass

- name: Echo Password
  when: adm_pass.changed
  debug:
    var: adm_pass.stdout
```

But In this case last task skips because it doesn't change, it's status is ok. How can I achieve my last task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q: ***"If a file exists echo out the contents of the file."***

A: The tasks below do the job

```yaml
    - stat:
        path: /var/lib/File
      register: result
    - slurp:
        src: /var/lib/File
      register: result
      when: result.stat.exists
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.content|b64decode }}"
```

---

Q: ***"Can we merge slurp and debug steps in the same task?"***

A: No. Both *slurp* and *debug* are modules. One task serves one module only. But, you can join the tasks in a block. For example, given the file

```
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /var/lib/File
test
```

The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "{{ my_file }}"
      register: result
    - block:
        - slurp:
            src: "{{ my_file }}"
          register: file
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ file.content|b64decode }}"
      when: result.stat.exists
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e my_file=/var/lib/File

PLAY [test_11] **************************************************

TASK [stat] *****************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [slurp] ****************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    test

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************
test_11: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The tasks in the block will be skipped if the file does not exist

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e my_file=/var/lib/FileX

PLAY [test_11] *****************************************************

TASK [stat] ********************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [slurp] *******************************************************
skipping: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
skipping: [test_11]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I think it is worth noting: The `lookup` happens on the ansible host, not the managed host.

Comment: yes as dgw mentioned, it's lookin on for file on ansible control machine. hence gives this error:

fatal: [jenkins]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /var/lib/File"}

Comment: Right. `slurp` is needed. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Right. Use `slurp`.

Comment: ok can we merge both slurp and debug step in same task? cause apparenly they've the same purpose. and I mean one task not nested syntax.

Comment: No. It's not possible. Both `debug` and `slurp` are modules. One task one module.